# Useragent in firefox not redirecting to mobile website

Tags: firefox, redirect, mobile, firefox-addon, user-agent

I have installed User Agent Switcher in my firefox and some of the websites when opened automatically redirects to mobile while some of them render desktop websites only.

For example nytinmes.com when opened automatically redirected to http://mobile.nytimes.com/?referrer= while thehindu.com didnt get redirected to m.thehindu.com. My phone mobile does redirect thehindu.com to m.thehindu.com though.

What is making the difference. How do I truly get mobile browser behaviour on my desktop browser?

Comment: Report this on the add-on feedback section or his support site. He'll find a way to make it compatible with all as that's what his add-on advertises. Yo uwill help him impove his add-on. He'll be motivated to fix this as well. Thus I think this topic is offtopic and may need a close.

Comment: Check the headers sent & received with an addon like [Live HTTP Headers 0.17](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/). It is possible that the headers are not understood or the site is looking for something else.